# Jquery script stops working when another script reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<td>
  <div class="status">1</div>
  <span class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</td>
```

I have this script:

```
<script>
  $('.status:contains("1") + span').removeClass('fa-times-circle').addClass('fa-sun-o');
</script>
```

The script basically removes and adds class depending on the text of the div 1 or 0. However, the script works only for 10 seconds then it reverts back to the default class which shows fa-times-circle. It stop when another script (see below) reload the data every 10-second interval.

```
<script>
  (function updateStafftable() {
    $.get('sql/staff-status.php', function(data) {
      $('.table-staffs').html(data);
      setTimeout(updateStafftable, 10000);
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Do you guys know why? Also, an important detail I would like to point out is that the html that I mentioned in the beginning is in the 'staff-status.php' which reload every 10-second interval. I just don't understand why this happens.

Comment: depends what has the class `table-staffs`. Basically, from what I can gather, you're like a painter who just painted the wall blue. But every 10 seconds, another painter comes by and will paint the wall white regardless of what was before it. Then you ask why the wall is white 10 seconds later makes me think you need to work out your logic first.

Comment: maybe add some more to this question regarding "table-staffs" table. If that is a parent of <div class="status">1</div> then it replaces it... and thus reverts your changes

Comment: It's interesting how JavaScript works in-conjunction with html. Problem solved when I include the script within the page that is being reloaded.

Comment: still have no idea what the problem was and how you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is not good but if you want to acheive your goal with minimal changes then put that script in success of ajax call

```
<script>
  (function updateStafftable() {
    $.get('sql/staff-status.php', function(data) {
      $('.table-staffs').html(data);
      $('.status:contains("1") + span').removeClass('fa-times-circle').addClass('fa-sun-o');
      setTimeout(updateStafftable, 10000);
    });
  })();
</script>
```

> Better way

edit logic in `staff-status.php` by putting `if` condition to assign class based on status like

```
   ...    
   if($status == 1){
     $class= 'fa-sun-o';
    }else{
     $class= 'fa-times-circle';
    }
    ....
    <td>
      <div class="status">$status</div>
      <span class="fa $class" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </td>
    ....
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Nirmal.